# How to display a resource string with a parameter in XAML

Tags: xaml

I can't figure out how to display in XAML a resource string that takes a parameter:

I have a public static class with a property that returns a string:

```
public static class Branding
{
    ...
    public static string Name { get { return "thename"; } }
}
```

and a resource string with a parameter `"Hello {0}"`, lets call it `NameLabel`,
I want to display "Hello thename" in a Label on a XAML window.

I can display just the contents of `Branding.Name` with this code

```
    <Label Content="{x:Static base:Branding.Name}" ...
```

or just the resource string with this code

```
    <Label Content="{x:Static res:Resources.NameLabel}" ...
```

but I can't find how to format the resource string with the name as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to format a label content with your "template" you could do the following:

```
<Label Content="yourContent" ContentStringFormat="yourTemplate" />
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent to ContentStringFormat for a TextBlock?

Comment: If you want to use a TextBlock,you have to do this `<TextBlock Content="{Binding yourContent, StringFormat=yourTemplate />` I'm typing without a VS here so its more or less what you have to write.